# IBM MobileFirst Quality Assurance - MQA Not Defined

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

I am getting the following error in my index.js:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MQA is not defined

I have the following code in my index.js file:

```
MQA.startNewSession({
    //Required for IBM MobileFirst Quality Assurance
    // or "MARKET" if it is production mode.

    mode: "QA",
    shake: true,
    protocol: 'http',
    host: 'ourhostnamehere:80',
    versionName: "1.0", // app release version
    android: {
      appKey: "91719217347da8e6daf648192dc774664978bba1",
      versionNumber: "1" // app version number
    }
     /*ios: {
         applicationKey: "<iOS MQA application key>",
         versionNumber: "1.0" // app version number
     }*/
},{
      success: function () { console.log("mqa success"); },
      error: function (e) { console.log("mqa failed: " + e); }
});
```

I have confirmed that both mqa.js and tracekit.js are loading in my app via chrome inspect.
What am I missing?

Comment: @Idan Adar - I was able to fix this error by putting it inside of wlCommonInit(). However now it is saying failed: Class not Found. What does this mean?

Comment: @Idan Adar However now it is saying failed: Class not Found. What does this mean?

Comment: I don't know. You haven't really provided anything that can be worked with... if you have a project you can upload, it could be debugged.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the project. What other information would be helpful? I am just trying to add this to a MFP8.0 Cordova Project using the Javascript SDKs.

Comment: Android or iOS?

Comment: Right now I am focusing on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 supports Cordova applications that are created at minimum with cordova-ios@**4.0.1** and cordova-android@5.1.1.

MobileFirst Quality Assurance currently does not support the required plug-in version minimum mentioned above, as such you cannot use MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 with MobileFirst Quality Assurance until the MQA team updates their Cordova plug-in to the required minimum.

Comment: I see that for the SDK for Apache Cordova. Can I use the Javascript SDK? It supports iOS 6.1 or later and Android 4.0 or later.

Comment: The JavaScript SDK is meant for Hybrid applications created in MobileFirst Studio 7.1. In MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 there is no more support for Hybrid apps like those in 7.1, rather only standard Cordova applications. What you need to do is contact the Quality Assurance team and have them update their Cordova plug-in to meet the requirements of newer Cordova releases, that's the problem here.

Comment: iOS 6.1 refers to the iOS OS version, not the Cordova plug-in version. QA is simply not supported in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 at this time.