# Testflight Invalid build while using Mobile Quality Assurance

Tags: ionic-framework, xcode8, mobilefirst-qa

I am new for ionic i added "Mobile Quality Assurance" sdk using below the tutorials

SDK Downloads : http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSJML5_6.0.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.saas.doc/topics/IOSSDKsForDownload.html

Installation - http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSJML5_6.0.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.saas.doc/topics/t_InstallingTheIOSLibraries.html

and my project contains "MFP" Plugin

Now the app is working well on devices, but if i uploaded to app store i am seeing "invalid binary"

Note: Before implementing "Mobile Quality Assurance" build shown on preparing for submission.

Comment: What is the MFP version?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what is the version of the IBM MobileFirst SDK you're using, but since you say you're using Ionic as the platform for creating your Cordova application, you may be using v8.0 of MobileFirst, in which case MQA is not supported. See here for more information: [IBM MobileFirst Quality Assurance - MQA Not Defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114509/ibm-mobilefirst-quality-assurance-mqa-not-defined)